# Questions regarding alias in Java

Tags: java, alias

```
public class Vector {

    private int x, y, z;

    public Vector(int x, int y, int z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public void add(Vector v) {
        x += v.x;
        y += v.y;
        z += v.z;
    }

    public void silly(int x, int y, int z) {
        this.x = ++x;
        this.y = y + 1;
        this.z += z;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getZ() {
        return z;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vector, <x = " + x + ", y = " + y + ", z = " + z + ">";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector a = new Vector(1, 0, 0);
        Vector b = new Vector(0, 1, 0);
        Vector c = a;
        int x = 1;
        int y = 2;
        int z = 3;
        a.add(b);
        b.add(b);
        c.add(c);
        c.silly(x, y, z);
        System.out.println("a: " + a);
        System.out.println("b: " + b);
        System.out.println("c: " + c);
        System.out.println("x: " + x + "\ty: " + y + "\tz: " + z);
    }
}
```

I have obviously been unclear in my question, sorry about that. I got this as practice from my teacher and I am supposed to explain the output of the last 4 lines in the code. I have no idea why the output looks as it does. I'm not very good at alias and so on. Someone might be able to give me an explanation? Thanks.

Comment: For me it is unclear what you "dont really understand" ? try to ask a clear question

Comment: What is the output of the last four lines in the main method? Can't really get my head around it.

Comment: I've run your code, and all works as expected. What's your problem?

Comment: You will learn a lot if you step through this with a debugger, and examine all the objects after each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Vector c = a;
```

means that you create reference which is linked to reference a and its object. You don't call a constructor there. You don't create any object there. Just new reference

Comment: @AxelNiklasson Not really: `a` and `c` are two *references to the same object*. You aren't editing either `a` or `c`; you are editing the one object they both refer to.

Comment: As far as I know you cant edit/change/update references. You can change/edit or something the object. So now, both a and c are linked to the same object. If you change something in this object, both a and c will see this changes

Answer (score 1):

The only question I can see is 'What is the relation between Vectors a and c?' So I'll answer that.

When you use the 'new' keyword you are creating a new object which is stored in the heap. So 'a' and 'b' are two separate objects when they have been instantiated. When you say:

```
Vector c = a;
```

You are not creating a new object in the heap, merely making a new reference to the same object. So now both 'a' and 'c' are referencing the same thing. If you change a, c will change, and vice versa.

When:

```
c.add(c);
```

Is called then the ints in c are simply being added to themselves.